# How to resolve message: No fill issue in android/flutter Admob?

Tags: flutter, admob, ads, flutter-android

Admob throws this error :

```
LoadAdError(code: 3, domain: com.google.android.gms.ads, message: No fill., responseInfo: ResponseInfo(responseId: null, mediationAdapterClassName: , adapterResponses: []))
```

my app is already in playstore and all verification process are done in admob, but still ads are not showing.

Comment: Did you found any solution or answer?